# Android NDK: Application targets deprecated ABI(s): armeabi error after update NDK

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Yesterday, after updating NDK I'm having these errors:

```
Error:(81) Android NDK: Application targets deprecated ABI(s): armeabi
Error:(82) Android NDK: Support for these ABIs will be removed in a 
future NDK release.
```

This links directed me to `setup-app.mk` file on lines

```
_deprecated_abis := $(filter $(NDK_DEPRECATED_ABIS),$(NDK_APP_ABI))
ifneq ($(_deprecated_abis),)
  $(call __ndk_warning,Application targets deprecated ABI(s): 
  $(_deprecated_abis))
  $(call __ndk_warning,Support for these ABIs will be removed in a 
  future NDK release.)
endif
```

I have no idea, how to solve this problem.
Any advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem and was just avoiding cleaning or rebuilding the whole project until I got the latest NDK update and the problem re-emerged.

This happens because even after removing the targets, there are still files present in `app/.externalNativeBuild` that refers to them.

To fix this I removed the Application.mk (which I was using to set the targets) and added this lines to app/build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {

        // ...

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' // 'x86', 'x86_64' may be added
        }
   }

   // ...

    task ndkClean(type: Delete) {
        // remove unused archs from build cache
        delete fileTree('.externalNativeBuild') {
            exclude defaultConfig.ndk.abiFilters.collect { '**/' + it }
        }
    }
    tasks.findByPath(':clean').dependsOn ndkClean
}
```

Comment: Commenting in case someone else has the same issue. I had to remove the : in the last line for my gradle build to find the clean task. Becore it was saying can't call dependsOn on a null object.

Comment: Thank you! The comment about "app/.externalNativeBuild" solved my problem. Kind of sad that a clean does not remove it.

Answer (score 4):

In Application.mk file, you should set APP_ABI:= armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips
then sync project. It would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove armeabi from your APP_ABI list.

As you can see from the source though, it should be a warning, not an error. How are you invoking ndk-build?

Comment: Nohow. I'm invoking app build only.

Comment: What do you mean? As in you're building via Android Studio/gradle?

Comment: ndk attached by local.properties, but I'm don't invoking it, I'm using clean, than rebuild, then run. Maybe I'm don't understand what are you meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has this issue, here are some things to try in order.

- Delete build folder, Then **Build > Clean Project, Build > Rebuild Project**
- If above doesn't work, add

  **APP_ABI:= armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a**

  in Application.mk file and link it from the app level gradle (Just like Android.mk is linked to) and try build again